# Why does the teacher put paste on her face?

Tags: plot-explanation, billy-madison

There is a strange scene in Billy Madison where Billy is cleaning erasers for one of his teachers -- Miss Lippy, a hippy-like lady who teaches an elementary class -- and Miss Lippy [puts a big dab of paste right on her face](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&ved=0CDIQtwIwAQ&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7jeNQ53iKfw&ei=mo32UuvXCoL4yQHRqYGAAQ&usg=AFQjCNGN_zODuDQrpD06Qc0GMO2fWCGuvw&sig2=sGBoBZROn50xY9DMjGKKjA&bvm=bv.60983673,d.aWc&cad=rja). The scene ends right after she does this.

Why does Miss Lippy put paste on her face?

Comment: Was she high on chalk dust? Really, no clue. Might be in-line with the "Little Person" in Happy Gilmore's [Happy Place](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9z5qpyxRR-A) ... No real explanation, it's just there to make you laugh while scratching your head. (At least everything that I've heard hasn't had a good explanation for the Little Person!)

Comment: Miss libby/lippy whatever it is was probably a sex fiend as she equated the glue to cum.

Comment: *"It was flour and water, and they said, 'You're gonna be sitting in a chair and you're gonna put paste on your face,'" she recalled, adding that she wasn't used to life on a movie set, without rehearsals. "I put the stick in [the paste] and put it right on top of my eyeball. They said, 'Oh my God, I can't believe you put it on your eye!' I kinda got in trouble because they had to re-do my makeup, but I think they used [the take]!"* - http://abcnews.go.com/Entertainment/billy-madison-turns-20-dina-platias-miss-lippy/story?id=28843222

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I agree with @Paulster2 - just to make you laugh while scratching your head. But I want to add that Billy comes back to the classroom while the teacher is performing a tortured dance of anguish, so I think the paste on her face is just another level of her psychosis.  Adam Sandler thinks it's funny to show that a sweet Kindergarten teacher has this troubled psychological condition underneath it all.  (And I remember laughing at the paste on the face, so I must think it's funny too!)

Answer (score -1):

Have you worked Kinder? It looks as though she is taking her time to find a happy place...I don't agree that she is troubled, more so she is fighting for her own sanity!

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question.